# Помогите исправить код на питоне. Тетрис

Tags: python, pygame

Пишу тетрис на языке питон.
Использую две Матрицы
Одну для очистки (SMatrix) Вторую для отрисовки (DMatrix)
Но столкнулся с рядом проблем:

1. Почему то вместе с динамической обновляется и статическая
2. При отрисовке появляется две линии из блоков (Хоть я и прописал условия отрисовки)
   Основной код

```
import pygame,random
from tetris import SMatrix,DMatrix,Tile

class Aplication():
    def __init__(self):
        self.scr = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
        self.MainGameSurface = pygame.Surface((200,400))
        self.ListT = [random.choice("OISZLJT")]*5
        self.Tile = Tile(random.choice("OISZLJT"),1)
        self.Tick = pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT,1000)
        self.History = []
        self.HistoryMove = []
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
                
    def update(self):
        for y,i in enumerate(DMatrix):
            for x,i1 in enumerate(DMatrix[y]):
                if i1 == 1:
                    if x != 0 or x != 11:
                        if y != 0 or y != 22:
                            pygame.draw.rect(self.MainGameSurface,(255,255,255),(20*x+1,20*y+1,18,18))
        self.scr.blit(self.MainGameSurface,(300,200))
        pygame.display.flip()
    
    def check_event(self):
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return 0
            if e.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
                self.Tile.Tick()
                self.History.append("Down")
            if e.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if e.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.Tile.x +=1
                    self.History.append("Move")
                    self.HistoryMove.append(1)
                if e.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.Tile.x -=1
                    self.History.append("Move")
                    self.HistoryMove.append(-1)
                if e.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.Tile.rviev +=1
                    self.History.append("Rot")
        for i in DMatrix:
            if 2 in i:
                if self.History[-1] == "Move": 
                    self.Tile.x += -self.HistoryMove[-1]
                    self.Tile.Tick()
                if self.History[-1] == "Rot": 
                    self.Tile.rviev -=1
                    self.Tile.Tick()
                if self.History[-1] == "Down":
                    self.Tile.static()
                    self.Tile = Tile(self.ListT[0],1)
                    self.ListT.pop(0)
                    self.ListT.append(random.choice("OISZLJT"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(0)
    app1 = Aplication()
    while True:
        id = app1.check_event()
        app1.update()
        if id == 0:
            raise SystemExit  
        app1.clock.tick(25)
```

Модуль:

```
vievs = {
    "O":{1:[[1,1],[1,1]],
       2:[[1,1],[1,1]],
       3:[[1,1],[1,1]],
       4:[[1,1],[1,1]]},
    "I":{1:[[1,1,1,1]],
         2:[[1],[1],[1],[1]],
         3:[[1,1,1,1]],
         4:[[1],[1],[1],[1]]},
    "S":{1:[[0,1,1],[1,1,0]],
         2:[[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]],
         3:[[0,1,1],[1,1,0]],
         4:[[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]]},
    "Z":{1:[[1,1,0],[0,1,1]],
         2:[[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]],
         3:[[1,1,0],[0,1,1]],
         4:[[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]]},
    "L":{1:[[1,0],[1,0],[1,1]],
       2:[[1,1,1],[1,0,0]],
       3:[[1,1],[1,0],[1,0]],
       4:[[0,0,1],[1,1,1]]},
    "J":{1:[[0,1],[0,1],[1,1]],
       2:[[1,0,0],[1,1,1]],
       3:[[1,1],[1,0],[1,0]],
       4:[[1,1,1],[0,0,1]]},
    "T":{1:[[1,1,1],[0,1,0]],
         2:[[0,1],[1,1],[0,1]],
         3:[[0,1,0],[1,1,1]],
         4:[[1,0],[1,1],[1,0]]}
}
MainMatrix = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
          ]
DMatrix = MainMatrix.copy()
SMatrix = MainMatrix.copy()

class Tile():
    def __init__(self,v,rv):
        self.viev = v
        self.rviev = rv
        self.y,self.x = 1,1
    
    def To_Matrix(self,Matrix):
        m1 = Matrix.copy()
        for y,i in enumerate(vievs[self.viev][self.rviev]):
            for x,i1 in enumerate(vievs[self.viev][self.rviev][y]):
                m1[y+self.y][x+self.x] += i1
        return m1.copy()

    def Tick(self):
        self.y+=1
        DMatrix = SMatrix.copy()
        DMatrix = self.To_Matrix(DMatrix)
    
    def static(self):
        self.y -=1
        self.To_Matrix(SMatrix)
```